# google play store warning: App Bundle contains native code, and recommend to upload deobfuscation file

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

When I am trying to update my existing ionic 4 application on the google play store which don't have any native code,
I am just promoting my app from the alpha channel to the production channel.

It shows 2 warning messages:

> 1. This App Bundle contains Java / Kotlin code, which can be deobfuscated. We recommend uploading a deobfuscation file so that your
>    crashes and ANRs can be more easily analyzed and resolved
> 2. This App Bundle contains native code and you have not uploaded any debugging symbols. We recommend uploading a symbol file so that your
>    crashes and ANRs can be more easily analyzed and resolved.

does anyone have an idea of how to get rid of these warning messages?

Comment: as message indicates, you need to uploading your mapping file to released version. Reference - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9848633?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you've built the App Bundle by Unity, the first warning can be solved by going to Project Settings -> Player -> Publishing Settings and changing "Release" from NONE to PROGUARD.